# MySQL: Table 'test.users_id' doesn't exist on LeetCode

Tags: mysql, sql

Before all, thanks your reading or suggestions, which is my honor.
When I solve this problem, My thought is to these banned numbers by legal users or drivers, dividing to the all numbers by users or drivers.I have meet this error, "Table 'test.users_id' doesn't exist
", which have no remind me because I have no use table `test`.

**The qustion link:**
[LeetCode](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/trips-and-users/)

**codes**

```sql
# Write your MySQL query statement below
select 
    distinct t1.Request_at as  `Day`, 
    around(count(s1.Request_at)/coount(s2.Request_at), 2) `Cancellation Rate`
from
(
    select t1.Request_at, t1.Request_at `Request_at`
    from
        Trips `t1` join Users `u1` on t1.Clinet_Id = u1.Users_Id join Users `u2` on t1.Driver_Id = u2.Users_Id
    where
        u1.Banned = 'No' and u2.Banned = 'No' and t1.Status = 'cancelled_by_driver' or t1.Status = 'cancelled_by_client'
) `s1`,
(
    select t2.Request_at, t2.Request_at `Request_at`
    from
        Trips `t2` join Users `u3` on t1.Clinet_Id = u3.Users_Id
        join Users_Id `u4` on t1.Driver_Id = u4.Users_Id
    where
        u3.Banned = 'No' and u4.Banned = 'No'
) `s2`
group by t1.Request_at;
```

Comment: OK, I just find a question, at the last of my codes, ```t1.Request_at``` is wrong, which should be ```s1.Request_at```. when it is have changed , my problem is not be solved.

Comment: should coount be count? also I don't think around is a function do you want round?

Comment: maybe you mean `join Users` rather than `join Users_Id` ?

Comment: OK，thanks so much, your comments have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Bryan Dellinger and Ian Kenney, which helps me.The answer codes:

```sql
SELECT T.request_at AS `Day`, 
    ROUND(
            SUM(
                IF(T.STATUS = 'completed',0,1)
            )
            / 
            COUNT(T.STATUS),
            2
    ) AS `Cancellation Rate`
FROM Trips AS T
JOIN Users AS U1 ON (T.client_id = U1.users_id AND U1.banned ='No')
JOIN Users AS U2 ON (T.driver_id = U2.users_id AND U2.banned ='No')
WHERE T.request_at BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-10-03'
GROUP BY T.request_at
```